# Green/Blue Deployments with several development teams

Tags: deployment, continuous-delivery, bluegreen

I am working in an AKS cluster environment with several clusters separated from each other.

I've been reading about Green/Blue deployments about testing a change in one cluster and then rerouting traffic to that cluster once everything is ok. For that I will have an additional cluster for each existing cluster.

My question is about having several teams deploying changes. If testing is made on a change of a single team, how do you suggest handling several teams all wanting to make changes at the same time? Also, how do you make sure a certain change testing doesn't starve other changes from being deployed and tested?